# Get <option> attributes in<input>

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, jsx

I have function that is returning me options for :

```
const codesList = () => {
  return businessCodes.map((code, index) => {
    return <option key={code.BusinessCode}>{code.IndustryName}</option>;
  });
};
```

Then I have the datalist and input field that is taking values:

```
      <input
            type="text"
            className="filter-select-form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Business Code"
            id="business-code"
            list="code-dataList"
            autoComplete="off"
          ></input>
        </div>
        {/* DATALISTS CODES*/}
        <datalist id="code-dataList">
          {RightFilterFunction.codesList()}
        </datalist>
```

After that in the function where I get the value of input field, I have the following situation:

```
const businessCode = document.getElementById("business-code").value;
```

With this part of code to the businessCode is assigned exactly code.IndustryName. I am wondering how it is possible to access this key property of options key={code.BusinessCode}. I want to businessCode to be assigned code.BusinessCode but datalist to remain with code.IndustryName.
Part of JSON (businessCodes array) which you will know why I prefer IndustryName to be visualised and BusinessCode to be sent to endpoints:

```
{
    BusinessCode: 111,
    IndustryName: "Crop Production"
  },
  {
    BusinessCode: 112,
    IndustryName: "Animal Production and Aquaculture"
  },
  {
    BusinessCode: 113,
    IndustryName: "Forestry and Logging"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `state` to keep a track of selected object from the codes array, so you have both `BusinessCode` and `IndustryName`

Avoid using jQuery in React as  much as possible. Check the code below:

```js
const businessCodes = [{
    BusinessCode: 111,
    IndustryName: "Crop Production"
  },
  {
    BusinessCode: 112,
    IndustryName: "Animal Production and Aquaculture"
  },
  {
    BusinessCode: 113,
    IndustryName: "Forestry and Logging"
  }];
  
const codesList = () => {
  return businessCodes.map((code, index) => {
    return <option key={code.BusinessCode}>{code.IndustryName}</option>;
  });
};

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedOption: {}};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    let selectedOption;
    let filtered = businessCodes.filter(item => item["IndustryName"] === event.target.value)
    
    if(filtered.length) selectedOption = filtered[0]
    else selectedOption = {}
    
    this.setState({selectedOption}, function(){
      if(Object.keys(this.state.selectedOption).length)
        console.log(this.state.selectedOption)
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Business Code"
            list="code-dataList"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        {/* DATALISTS CODES*/}
        <datalist id="code-dataList">
          {codesList()}
        </datalist>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually You are using the it incorrectly and never try to access DOM like this getElementById("business-code") in React. It is a bad practice and always gets value through the onChange Event.

Use value instead of keys and the problem will be solved.

```js
{this.state.businessCodes.map((code, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={code.BusinessCode}>
              {code.IndustryName}
            </option>
          ))}
```

FULL CODE How It works on React.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    businessCodes: [
      {
        BusinessCode: 111,
        IndustryName: "Crop Production"
      },
      {
        BusinessCode: 112,
        IndustryName: "Animal Production and Aquaculture"
      },
      {
        BusinessCode: 113,
        IndustryName: "Forestry and Logging"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="code"
          className="filter-select-form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Business Code"
          id="business-code"
          list="code-dataList"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <datalist id="code-dataList">
          {this.state.businessCodes.map((code, index) => (
            <option key={index} value={code.BusinessCode}>
              {code.IndustryName}
            </option>
          ))}
        </datalist>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Basically this changes nothing